# Google Apps Script double deleting rows in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onEdit() {
var openRequests = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Open Requests');
var lastRowOpen = openRequests.getLastRow();

var closedRequests = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Closed Requests');
var lastRowClose = closedRequests.getLastRow();

var closed = openRequests.getRange(2,8,lastRowOpen,1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < lastRowOpen; i++)
{
    if (closed[i][0].toString() == 'Yes')
    {
        var line = i+2;
        if (closedRequests.getLastRow() == 1)
        {
            openRequests.getRange(line,1,1,9).copyTo(closedRequests.getRange(2,1,1,9));
            closedRequests.getRange(2,9,1,1).setValue(new Date());
            openRequests.deleteRow(line);
        }
        else
        {
            openRequests.getRange(line,1,1,9).copyTo(closedRequests.getRange(lastRowClose+1,1,1,9));
            closedRequests.getRange(lastRowClose+1,9,1,1).setValue(new Date());
            openRequests.deleteRow(line);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have set up a trigger to run onEdit.  What it does is check a column called `Closed` to see if it says `Yes`.  The `Closed` column has a data validation drop down menu with the value `Yes` in it.

So when I click on the drop down menu and select `Yes`, it should copy the whole row to another sheet called `Closed Requests` then delete that row from the spreadsheet called `Open Requests`.

The issue I am having is that about 50% of the time, it deletes the row I select `Yes` to but it ALSO deletes the row below it (and about 50% of the time when this happens, only some times does the second deleted row show up in `Closed Requests`, the other times the whole row just disappears forever unless I undo).

From what I can tell, the `deleteRow()` function deletes the whole row and shifts all rows below it up a row to fill in the blank.  So the row below the one meant to be deleted gets shifted up to the same row and also gets deleted.  I don't know why the function is getting called twice though.

I tried adding some delays but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var eRange = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var openRequests = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Open Requests');
  var closedRequests = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Closed Requests');
  var nextRowClose = (closedRequests.getLastRow()?closedRequests.getLastRow()+1:2);

  if(eRange.getSheet().getName()=="Open Requests" && eRange.getColumn()==8 && eRange.getValue()=="Yes") {
    openRequests.getRange(eRange.getRow(), 1, 1, 9)
      .copyTo(closedRequests.getRange(nextRowClose, 1));
    closedRequests.getRange(nextRowClose, 9).setValue(new Date());
    openRequests.deleteRow(eRange.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working so far.  Can you tell me what I was doing that caused the double delete?

Comment: Hi Jack, I do not know why your script is acting up. I have seen the likes before when modifying documents from within a loop. The solution I have proposed goes directly to the source without looping through prior responses as choosing yes from a drop down would indicate that that should not be necessary. Hopes this meets you needs. Regards, Michael

Comment: P.S. If you wish to pursue the issue a more definitive answer might be acquired be filing and issue in the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker at:  https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveRange" of undefined.` from the apps-script summary e-mail referring to the line `var eRange = e.source.getActiveRange();`.  It still works but I get one error each time I delete something (in the e-mail).

Comment: I don't understand <<It still works but I get one error each time I delete something (in the e-mail).>> What sheet and cell are you deleting when this occurs?

Comment: The Open Requests sheet.  I just use the drop down menu and select `Yes` in the column called `Closed`.  It deletes it and copies the row to the Closed Requests sheet.  It is working as expected with no double delete.

But every day I get an e-mail from the apps-script-notification (the notification rule is set to send one out every midnight) saying the script failed to execute properly.  The time listed corresponds to times I used the script to delete (Yes in the Closed column).

Comment: Have you cleaned out all other scripts and triggers that were generated in trying to come up with a solution to this? You should not need to set any triggers as the onEdit(e) should run without setting triggers? It sounds like something else is going on.

Comment: Oh, so the `e` in `onEdit(e)` already runs without triggers? I still had the trigger set.  I'll try it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could try iterating backwards as it was [mentioned to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058019/delete-a-row-in-google-spreadsheet-base-on-value-of-cell-in-row).  Throwing in a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the delete may help too.

Comment: Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Not the exact same.  Did switching to backwards make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

@Jack, I have a similar use case to you.  My code is the backwards one that BryanP discusses.  My code is more or less here:  ["Batch removal of task items where status = 'Done'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221264/open-google-docs-spreadsheet-by-name/14221807#14221807).  It is because I remove them in a batch that I use the backwards method whereby the removal of a row with a higher row number will not disturb the row number of any rows with a lower row number.

But you are not removing rows in batch mode, so maybe backwards shouldn't make a difference (perhaps unless two users use the sheet and delete at the same time?)

So thought I'd try your code.  I shoe horned your code into the onedit() function that is already present on my spreadsheet (which is used to colour rows red after a period of inactivity, and to put in a timestamp once the task is actually attended).

Then to test I used a copy of one of our spreadsheet which had already 50 rows/tasks in it.  I manually filled in the required cells in a row and selected Done from the cell with the dropdown (I changed your code to expect "Done" rather than "Yes").  I repeated this for 20 rows.

The Result: Your code succeeded as you had expected it to every one of the 20 times ... no double deletes, always copying data across.  It worked for me without introducing delays nor SpreadsheetApp.flush().

I don't have a solid suggestion I am afraid.  In passing I mention the known fault where the spreadsheet has not properly refreshed itself, so does not show the deleted rows; this can be checked for by manually refreshing the spreadsheet when this fault appears.  (However, the indications of this fault does not seem to logically fit with your report about the double copying over of two sequential rows.)

Answer (score 0):

Thread lock? Sounds like a thread lock problem. Try:

```
function onEdit() {

 // ****** add lock code
 var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
 var hasMutex = lock.tryLock(100);
 if(hasMutex==false) {
   return;
 }
 // *** end

 var openRequests = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Open Requests');
 var lastRowOpen = openRequests.getLastRow();

 var closedRequests = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Closed Requests');
 var lastRowClose = closedRequests.getLastRow();

 var closed = openRequests.getRange(2,8,lastRowOpen,1).getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < lastRowOpen; i++)
 {
    if (closed[i][0].toString() == 'Yes')
    {
       var line = i+2;
       if (closedRequests.getLastRow() == 1)
       {
          openRequests.getRange(line,1,1,9).copyTo(closedRequests.getRange(2,1,1,9));
          closedRequests.getRange(2,9,1,1).setValue(new Date());
          openRequests.deleteRow(line);
       }
        else
       {

   openRequests.getRange(line,1,1,9).copyTo(closedRequests.getRange(lastRowClose+1,1,1,9));
        closedRequests.getRange(lastRowClose+1,9,1,1).setValue(new Date());
        openRequests.deleteRow(line);
        }
      }
  }


 // ****** add lock code
  lock.releaseLock();    

 // *** end

}
```

Questions:

1) how many people were using the spreadsheet at the time.

2) how often does it happen.

Comment: One person was using it.  When it happens, it happens a couple times in a row.  Some times it doesn't even happen at all.

Comment: You could remove the "cell style drop down menu" - sounds like it is the cause of the edit being called twice.