# Google Apps Script to access Google Sheet in a folder via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Suppose I have a drive with the following structure:

Under *My drive*:

- google_sheet_E
- Main_Folder

  - Folder_A
  - Folder_B

    - google_sheet_C (in google sheet format)
    - MS_excel_D.xls (in  excel format, upload to drive directly)

Note: google_sheet_E is located on the top layer of the drive, whereas, the C, and D, are located few levels below.

I would like to reference some data from google_sheet_C and MS_excel_D.xls to google_sheet_E.

In Google Apps Script, my current method is to get by ID, but I find this method inconvenient, since I have to get ID every time, therefore I am planning to use the file name instead. Is there any method/function to access a sheet similar to the path system in Windows? (i.e. Traverse the folders.)

Another question: Is there any good method to let users share from their drive to the spreadsheet automatically under a specific path?

Comment: You can use [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) to access files using folders and filenames: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29990059), for example.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any method/function to access a sheet similar to the path system in Windows?

[Bruce MacPherson has published just such a function](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/driveapppathfolder):

```js
/**
 * Returns a DriveApp folder object corresponding to the given path.
 *
 * From: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/driveapppathfolder
 */
function getDriveFolderFromPath (path) {
  return (path || "/").split("/").reduce ( function(prev,current) {
    if (prev && current) {
      var fldrs = prev.getFoldersByName(current);
      return fldrs.hasNext() ? fldrs.next() : null;
    }
    else { 
      return current ? null : prev; 
    }
  },DriveApp.getRootFolder()); 
}﻿
```

You could use it like this:

```js
// Get handle for folder
var folder = getDriveFolderFromPath("Main_Folder/Folder_B");

// Find file by name within folder. (Assumes just one match.)
var fileId = folder.getFilesByName("google_sheet_C").next().getId();

// Open spreadsheet using fileId obtained above.
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
...
```